# как извлечь последние цифры какого-либо класса в html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

я хочу сделать чтоб классы можно было использовать как переменные.

например ... если задаешь класс `width_` некоторому элементу, а затем пишешь какое либо значение, то он трансформируется в соответствии с последними цифрами заданного класса после `_` итд

пример: `<div class='width_200 height_50'>ширина этого блока 200px и высота-50px</div>`

как это возможно? и есть ли какая-либо функция, которая удаляет первые N букв в слове и затем присваивает полученное свойство определенному элементу?

желательно на jquery

Comment: Такие вещи, делаются в в самом css задайте сразу все классы, с нужными размерами. Или остается только js который будет обрабатывать css

Comment: да, я в курсе:D мне просто интересно..

Comment: Ну так тогда вы должны знать, что чистый css не подразумевает переменных. Остается только js. Через `el.style.whidth=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, например:

```js
$('div').each(function(){
  let width = 0;
  let height = 0;
  let params = $(this).attr('class').split(' '); //делаем содержимое класса элементами массива
  
  for(let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) { //проходим по массиву
    if(params[i].includes('width')) { //проверяем, есть ли там width
      width = Number(params[i].substr(params[i].lastIndexOf('_')+1)); //получаем значение width
    }
    else if(params[i].includes('height')) { //проверяем, есть ли там height
      height = Number(params[i].substr(params[i].lastIndexOf('_')+1)); //получаем значение height
    }
  }
  
  $(this).css({'width': width, 'height': height}) //устанавливаем стили
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='width_200 height_50'></div>
<div class='width_100 height_150'></div>
<div class='width_300 height_100'></div>
```